# Jenkins track custom values across builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a test that produces accuracy values for an algorithm at the end of each build. I can "publish" these values as a table per-build which is nice, but I'd like to see how these values change from build to build in something like a "dashboard" view, where say the values from the last N jobs are compared as columns in a table cells, and values that have gone up are colored green while values that have gone down are colored red, etc.

Is there a way (plugins, etc.) to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to spend some time on it, and set up real dashboard/monitoring:

- install [FluentD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FluentD+Plugin)
- add [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com) as storage
- configure [FluentD daemon](http://www.fluentd.org) to push data to Influx
- install [Grafana](https://grafana.net) dashboard

As result you will have scalable performance friendly solution for monitoring - with tables, trends, everything you want.
I know it looks like list is huge... but this setup takes only 2-4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Four years too late, but I think you want the Plot plugin :) https://plugins.jenkins.io/plot/